# Condensed mathematics

Tags: gn.general-topology, condensed-mathematics

I have a little technical question on Peter Scholze's [lectures on condensed mathematics](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf).

On page 12, right above the Proof of Theorem 2.2, he says that for extremally disconnected sets the condition (ii) on page 7 is automatic. I can't see why. I understand that the map is injective under the presence of sections, but why is it surjective?

This assertion is then used in the proof of Theorem 2.2 and I guess, it was the reason for introducing extremally disconnected spaces here, so I believe that it is true, but I just can't see why.

Comment: You should make your question self-contained.  Also (not instead) you should provide a link to Scholze's notes.

Comment: It must be true because Lean says so https://github.com/leanprover-community/lean-liquid/blob/a1f009de0f88731492e998e4fd8f27de3f6952af/src/condensed/extr/equivalence.lean#L311 .

Comment: @Kevin Buzzard: Nice. But I would nevertheless like to see a proof.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/leanprover-community/lean-liquid/blob/a1f009de0f88731492e998e4fd8f27de3f6952af/src/condensed/extr/basic.lean#L590) is the relevant result, the rest should mathematically easy. The proof is of course there, but it is a little bit obscure if you're not used to Lean.

Comment: I find this exchange between Kevin and Echo to be one of the funniest I've seen on mathoverflow. It would make a great epigraph for the right chapter of the right book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key point is to use the fact that extremally disconnected sets are projective (in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces) to note the coequalizer diagram involved in the analogue of condition (ii) is a [*split* coequalizer.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+coequalizer)

I'll explain some additional details in the next paragraphs, but first it's worthwhile to note that there is a small subtlety in formulating the analogue of condition (ii) because the pullback of extremally disconnected sets need not be extremally disconnected. Rather, you can always find an extremally disconnected presentation of the pullback.

So one way to formulate the analogue of condition (ii), for a presheaf $T$ on the category of extremally disconnecteds, is as follows:
For all surjective morphisms $X \to B$ of extremally disconnected sets, and all surjective morphisms $R \to X \times_B X$ where $R$ is extremally disconnected (and the pullback is computed in $\mathrm{CompHaus}$, say), the corresponding diagram
$$T(B) \to T(X) \rightrightarrows T(R)$$
is an equalizer diagram.

This diagram is obtained by applying $T$ to the coequalizer diagram
$$R \rightrightarrows X \to B,$$
where the two maps $R \to X$ are the compositions of $R \to X \times_B X$ with the two projections.

To see that the first diagram is a (split) equalizer, it suffices to show that the second is a split coequalizer.
We can construct such a splitting as follows.
First, since $\pi : X \to B$ is surjective, and $B$ is projective, we can find a splitting $\sigma : B \to X$, so that $\pi \circ \sigma = 1$.
Next, consider the map $X \to X \times_B X$ whose composition with the first projection to $X$ is the identity and whose composition with the second projection is $\sigma \circ \pi$ (since $\sigma$ is a splitting of $\pi$, the two maps to $B$ do indeed coincide, so we get such a map from the universal property of the pullback).
Now the map $R \to X \times_B X$ is surjective and $X$ is projective, so we can lift this map $X \to X \times_B X$ to a map $\tau : X \to R$ with the property that the compositions $X \to R \to X\times_B X \to X$ are $1$ and $\sigma\circ\pi$ respectively.
The two maps $\sigma$ and $\tau$ then give us the desired splitting of the coequalizer diagram.

Finally, to add to the comments on the original question, this was formalized in Lean (as part of the Liquid Tensor Experiment) as the following lemma:
https://github.com/leanprover-community/lean-liquid/blob/a1f009de0f88731492e998e4fd8f27de3f6952af/src/condensed/extr/basic.lean#L262

Comment: Am I the only one finding this kind of proof quite far outside what might reasonably be called “automatic”?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda "Automatic" here might mean "does not need to be explicitly postulated as an additional condition but follows as a logical consequence" rather than "is trivial to prove."

Comment: @Carl-Fredrik Tim's comment tracks with the definitions of automatic as _working by itself with little or no direct human control_, or _done or occurring spontaneously, without conscious thought or attention_. Some proofs flow from the interaction of a number of formal properties while not being themselves short: a "follow your nose" proof, at least for those intimate with the particular formalism. Perhaps you were thinking of "immediate" rather than "automatic"?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I suppose OP is intimate with the particular formalism, and yet seems to have not been able to follow their nose in spite of even a good deal of conscious thought. I find @TimothyChow’s explanation much more convincing.

Comment: @Carl-Fredrik I can imagine that for the authors of the text, such an argument is, relative to the more sophisticated ideas throughout, rather more pedestrian.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to MO, @Adam!

Comment: @Adam Topaz: Great answer! It was indeed the notion of a split coequalizer diagram, that I hadn't seen before. Cheers, Echo